# Multicasting Error on OSX: Can't assign requested address

Tags: macos, ip, config, multicast

I have configured the desired multicast address 224.0.0.1 and is active on en0 but when I run my program it still gives me the "Can't assign requested address"? Anyone one know why? all help is truely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

224.0.0.1 is a well known address

http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml

Try an address like 239.192.0.1